# how to override Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tabs

[image: Carbon Kit dynamic tabs bar]

In this image two view controller first contain all tabs items and second is ViewController three(named) as shown.
Here 'viewcontrollerThree' is a button. When I click this button and trying to add a badge value in navigation bar in a UIBarbutton. My
problem is tabs items navigation bar overlap the second view controller navigation bar so value not shown?
how to resolve it ??

Answer (score 0):

I think if you hide a navigation bar in your navigation controller and make your own custom view like navigation bar containing all the buttons. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Both views contain own navigation bar in carbon kit framework but second one not visible

Comment: I have downloaded that cocoa control but I am not exactly understanding what your problem is. Can you please elaborate little more details about it. Please share that overlapping photo

Comment: unfortunately I solve this issue thanks for your anticipation.

Comment: @UmeshVerma what was solution?